# Minimum version of Maven, JAVA SE and Docker

Tags: dropwizard, dropwizard-templates

I would like to know the minimum version of Maven and Java SE required to build a microservice using Dropwizard v1.3.20 (latest release as on 06-March-2020) ?

If I know the minimum version of Docker also, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 is the minimally required java version to run DropWizard.
Any docker that has java8 will work.